# is the overflow error a result of bad formatting?

Tags: python, floating-point

Function I tried to replicate:

[image: Function I tried to replicate]

doing a project for coursework in which I need to make the blackbody function and manipulate it in some ways.
I'm trying out alternate equations and in doing 2 of them i keep getting over flow error.

this is the error message:

```
 alt2_2 = (1/((const_e**(freq/temp))-1))

OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

`temp` is given in kelvin (im using 5800 as my test value as it is approximately the temp of the sun)

`freq` is speed of light divided by whatever wavelength is inputted

```
freq = (3*(10**8))/wavelength
```

in this case i am using `0.00000005` as the test value for `wavelength`.

and const `e` is `2.7182`

first time using stack. also first time doing a project on my own, any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be really helpful to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72384304/edit) the question and include actual python code that generates this error. To format code you just need to indent the lines 4 spaces.

Comment: Have you done the math on this?  Your `freq` will be `6x10**15`.  That means `freq/temp` will be `1x10**12`.  Raising `e` to that power gives a number with about `4x10**11` digits, which is vastly more than a double-precision float will hold.  I think your numbers are wrong.

Comment: I suspect either your units are wrong or you're dividing when you should be multiplying.

Comment: Are you trying for the denominator of the Planck function?  That's not `f/T`.  That's `h * c / (f * k * T)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks. I havent been going through the code with calculator to realise how stupid the numbers seem. I dont understand how freq/ temp can be used as a power of e and not be an overflow, so perhaps i've understood the equation incorrectly. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Barmar don't know how you did it but thanks for cleaning up my post. and yh i think i am using an incorrect formula

Comment: @TimRoberts I'll be honest, I dont understand the physics. I was just using an alternate equation i found for the spectral radiance on wikepedia lol. I have another formula function which seems to give a tangible result. but when trying this and another alternative formula, i again get an overflow error in both lines where the constant e resides.

Comment: Show us the function you're trying to compute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And did you leave out the constants on purpose?  Because with your values, (hf/kT) results in 49.5, and it's very much possible to take e**49.5.

Comment: `const_e` is far from the real e value, and to get `e^x` in almost all programming languages you'll use the `exp` function

Answer (score 0):

This does the blackbody computation with your values.

```
import math

# Planck constant
h = 6.6e-34
# Boltzmann constant
k = 1.38e-23
# Speed of light
c = 3e+8

# Wavelength
wl = 0.00000005
# Temp
T = 5800
# Frequency
f = c/wl

# This is the exponent for e (about 49).
k1 = h*f / (k*T)
# This computes the spectral radiance.
Bvh = 2*f*f*f*h / (math.exp(k1)-1)
print(Bvh)
```

Output:

```
9.293819741690355e-08
```

Since we only used one or two digits on the way in, the resulting value is only good to one or two digits, 9.3E-08.

Comment: Oh God. If you saw my code you would laugh. you have made it so much cleaner and simplified. About the constants, I'm supposed to put it to 4 sig figs or dec places which is why i haven't used very accurate or pre existing constants for these numbers. appreciate it Tim.